# Shortest formula to add Column to Array in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

A 2D Array with unpredictable size in Google Sheets :

```
name | age 
Sam  | 20
Sim  | 30
Jim  | 25
```

To be converted to (Added a constant string A)

```
name | age | Semester
Sam  | 20  | A
Sim  | 30  | A
Jim  | 25  | A
```

A formula like

`={A1:B,"A"}` Doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Figured an easy way to do this,

```
=query(A1:B,"select A,B,'A' where A is not null label 'A' ''")
```

This solves the problem.

Comment: I am afraid your query will place `A` even when there are no values in `A` or `B`. Is this what you really want?

Comment: Just add " where A is not null" to solve problem mentioned by @marikamitsos (if needed)

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(V2:V="",,"A"))
```

[image]

**Without a formula**
Or you can place `A` in cell `C2` and double click on the hair cross on the bottom right corner of the cell.

Answer (score 0):

shortest would be:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="",,"A"))
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion you can put the following on your `C1` cell:

`={"Semester";arrayformula(if(len(a2:a),"A",))}`

Then, if you make a filter and sort, it will preserve the values of the whole column:

[image]